# Comma as decimal separator in read_excel for Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a excel file with 119 sheets that I would like to get the data to plot multiple graphs. The problem is that the numeric values have comma as a decimal separator. And I have read that, differently from read_csv, the read_excel function in Pandas does not have this option.

I intend to load specific columns from some of selected sheets and build a merged graph using a for loop.

One of the alternatives that I saw (but it is kind of an overkill) is to transform each of the sheets into a specific csv file and load them and use the option of comma as decimal separator). Is there any alternative that I can load the data correctly without having to recourse to this alternative?

Thanks!

Comment: hi! Is any one of the answers below working? If so & if you wish, you might consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) one of them to signal others that the issue is resolved. If not, you can provide feedback so they can be improved (or removed altogether)

Answer (score 2):

Well unlike `read_csv()` method `read_excel()` method doesn't support `decimal` parameter:

But after loading your dataset you can use:

```
df = pd.read_excel('yourexcel.xlsx')
#loading dataset

cols=#your list of column that you want to convert
df[cols]=df[cols].replace(',','.',regex=True).astype(float)
```

OR

Other way is to create a function and use `converters` parameter in `read_excel()` method:

```
def typecast_float(value):
    try:
        return float(value.replace(',', '.'))
    except:
        return value

#Finally:

df=pd.read_excel("sample.xlsx", converters={'column_name': typecast_float})
```

Comment: Starting in version 1.4.0 pandas supports `decimal` parameter for `read_excel()`.

Answer (score 1):

as simple as:

```
pd.read_excel(file_locale, decimal=',')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the thousands separator:

```
df = pd.read_excel('yourexcel.xlsx', thousands=',')
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `decimal`.

`df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', decimal=',')`