# How to export a DataFrame to Excel with Pandas using a comma as the decimal separator

Tags: pandas

How can I export a DataFrame to Excel with Pandas using a comma as the decimal separator for the output file?

I have tried:

```
df = pd.read_html(html_str, decimal=',', thousands=' ')
df.to_excel('test.xlsx', index=None)
```

However, this will export the file with `.` as the decimal separator.

Basically, it's the same question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68449326/comma-as-decimal-separator-in-read-excel-for-pandas) one except I want to **write** the data to an Excel file instead of *reading* data from an Excel file. I am surprised and confused to see that `read_excel` supports the `decimal='.'` option, but not `to_excel`. What the heck?

Comment: If you want to use comma as delimiter, probably you need to use csv. Excel stores data in cells, so why would you need to say specifically what type of delimiter to use?

Comment: Sorry I meant to write decimal separator, not delimiter. I have updated the question.

Comment: Decimal seperators are more formating of your data so is generally outside the scope of pandas. You will need to look packages that you can use to apply formating to excel workbooks